# Repeat elememts based on another elements in the nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a nested list e.g., `ls=[((0,3),(1,0),(2,2),(3,0)),((0,0),(1,3),(2,2),(3,0))]`.

And I would like to have the following modified list:

`modified_ls=[((0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(2,0),(3,0)),((0,0),(1,0),(1,0),(1,0),(2,0),(2,0),(3,0))]`

There the element (x,0) in `modified_ls` is repeated by N (N!=0) times which is based on the element (x, N) in `ls`.

Here is what I do (quite stupid):

```
ls=[((0,3),(1,0),(2,2),(3,0)),((0,0),(1,3),(2,2),(3,0))]
modified_temp_ls=[]
for ii in ls:
    
    for jj in ii:
        temp=jj[1]
        if temp==0:
            modified_temp_ls.append(jj) 
        else:
            while temp:
                modified_temp_ls.append((jj[0],0))
                temp-=1
                

ls2=modified_temp_ls[0:int(len(modified_temp_ls)/2)]
ls3=modified_temp_ls[int(len(modified_temp_ls)/2):int(len(modified_temp_ls))]
modified_ls=[]
modified_ls.append(tuple(ls2))
modified_ls.append(tuple(ls3))
```

Are there any simple way to do it (e.g, without using ls2 and ls3, etc.)? Thank you very much in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: I tried for-loop things, but i can only get something like modified_ls=[(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(2,0),(3,0),(0,0),(1,0),(1,0),(1,0),(2,0),(2,0),(3,0)]. well, I can then do something like mod%7 and try to split as ((0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(2,0),(3,0)), ((0,0),(1,0),(1,0),(1,0),(2,0),(2,0),(3,0)). I wonder whether there are direct way that can give the output such that I don't need do index mod%7. @Jab

Comment: you can do something like this:
```for x in ls:
dicts = dict(x)
or y in dicts.items():
print(y[1])```
And after you can use the numbers to multiply for the intervals that you need.

Comment: Are you sure that's the spec?  Why should `(1,0)` and `(1,1)` product the same result?

Comment: yes, I am sure this is what I want due to some specific reason. The second number is for how many time I want to repeat. But for N is 0 and 1, I just keep as (x,0) @TimRoberts

Comment: @Jab, thanks for the asking. I edited and added my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just list manipulation.  Generate the individual sequences, then use `sum` to combine them into a single list.

```
ls=[((0,3),(1,0),(2,2),(3,0)),((0,0),(1,3),(2,2),(3,0))]
accum = []
for k in ls:
    accum.append(sum([ [(i,0)]*max(1,n) for i,n in k ],[]))
print(accum)
```

Output:

```
[[(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)]]
```

Or for the obligatory one liner:

```
ls=[((0,3),(1,0),(2,2),(3,0)),((0,0),(1,3),(2,2),(3,0))]
accum = [sum([[(i,0)]*max(1,n) for i,n in k ],[]) for k in ls]
```

Comment: looks very nice, thanks!